# Rotate text - Managed DirectX (C#)

Tags: c#, fonts, directx, managed-directx

I am currently developing a little application with a highly-dynamic GUI which needs a lot of refreshing and drawing. To archive this, I am using managed DirectX.
I successfully painted a little string in a specific font to specific coordinates, but I have no idea on how I could rotate the drawn text...

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found no native method to archive my goal.

So I painted the Font on a bitmap, created a texture and used sprites to draw my font texture.